# object mapper conversion issue when string contains'\/' patterns

Tags: java, mapper, mongo-jackson-mapper

I have following type of token that as to be send as it is in request.

//token contains following value
token = "ABCD/saljljlkljljljl";

class Token{
        public String token;

```
    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }

    public void setToken(String token) {
        this.token = token;
    }


}
```

when I try to convert it to string using object mapper class, it converts it as follows.
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.writeValueAsString(token)

{"token":"ABCD\/saljljlkljljljl"}

Note one more '\' added in front of '/' due to which my calls are failing.Don't no why its not reflecting even in stackoverflow reader pane also.

Please help out on this.

Comment: What version of everything? Have you tried it in Jackson without mongo?

Comment: jackson core and mapper are from 1.7.1 and its with out mongo.